# Postfix deferred queue

Tags: postfix, ubuntu-18.04, queue

I search and search and do not find answer. I have problem with Polish email providers and try to talk with them but ... can somebody tell my what means this numbers for `qshape deferred`

[image]

I'm talking about numbers: 5, 10, 20, 40, 80 ... 1280+ etc.

Answer (score -1):

http://www.postfix.org/qshape.1.html

> The qshape program helps the administrator understand the Postfix queue
> message distribution in time and by sender domain or recipient  domain.

In the columns you have time periods and in the row domains. So for op.pl there is total 40 deferred messages 16 of them older than 80 minutes.

If you go through the queue you should see maybe some reasons why they were each message deffered. What about `mailq`, are there any reasons?

Comment: I know reasons and try to negotiate with emails providers ... thanks for answer.

Comment: sorry but it's not minutes ... i resend all mails in queue "postqueue -f" and after few minutes it's look similar

Comment: Can you look at the times in the headers in one of the older emails? What is the time difference between the original sending and now?